# Excel errors out on existing sheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013

I am writing a VBA macro to reset certain regions of a calculation workbook that I frequently use. My calculate macro hides irrelevant sheets when it runs. I want the reset macro to make all the sheets visible. So, I wrote this code:

```
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    ws.Visible = True
Next ws
```

But, when I run it, it always errors out on a specific worksheet. The exact error message is this:
[image: Error message]
What am I doing wrong? The workbook does contain some "chart" worksheets. But, I am getting the error for a standard worksheet. I also don't have `dim ws as Worksheet` because then it cannot work with chart sheets.

Comment: Check if the worksheet is protected.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets` to `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets`

Also might be worth checking if the workbook itself is protected.